# Managing local-only changes with git

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-merge

On my local branch, I have some personal (local-only) changes to a Makefile (just changing the path to the compiler). Obviously I don't want to commit those changes in as they are only relevant to me. However, if I don't commit them then I get an error when I try to sync with the remote branch:

```
% git fetch upstream
% git merge upstream/master
error: Your local changes to 'Makefile' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

Stashing and then un-stashing the file every time this happens seems tedious. On Perforce for example, you would just move those file(s) to a separate change list and resolve merge conflicts where necessary.

What I want to happen is for git to automatically merge my local Makefile with the remote one (where possible), but without having to commit it. How would I got about doing that?

Comment: Why Not just let git ignore the makefile?

Comment: @dasheddot: I don't want to ignore the file. If someone adds a new command to the makefile then I still want to receive that change when I merge, I just don't want to commit my changes to that file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are likely several ways to approach this problem, here's my thought.

Make a new `makefix` branch and commit the makefile there. Whenever you need to make the project, switch to that branch. You can work in `master` and just keep merging, or rebasing the `makefix` branch against `master`.

The general idea is that you're creating a branch containing your `Makefile` that is never pushed.

Personally I would rebase `makefix` against `master` so my `Makefile` changes always stayed ahead of the actual pushable code. It just *feels* cleaner in my head.

### Code Example

```
git branch makefix
git checkout makefix
```

Make your changes to `Makefile`

```
git add Makefile
git commit -m "Add Local Makefile Changes to Compiler Path"
```

For every-day work

```
git checkout master
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master

git checkout makefix
git rebase master
```

It's long and ugly, so I hope someone else has a better way =]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said, it is a bit long, so I hope someone knows a simpler solution. I would be quite surprised if there's no simple way for managing local-only changes.

Comment: The problem as I see it, you want local changes that 1) are not pushed, but 2) are ahead of the remote version for tracked files. You could also rebase your local commits each time, and just be careful not to push HEAD, but this seems more error prone.

Comment: Certainly requires a few commands, but by far the cleanest way to handle this imho, so +1. However, I'd go for `git merge master` instead of `git rebase master`: That leaves the old states of the makefix branch intact, creating a ladder between the two branches that basically records both all the states that you want to publish plus all those states with your local changes applied.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably easier to let git do the rebase autmatically, i.e. create a local branch, configure rebase, add your changes, pull ...

```
git checkout -b mybranch origin/master
git config branch.mybranch.rebase true
```

Adapt the Makefile to your needs ...

```
git add Makefile
git commit -m 'My local-only Makefile.'
```

From now on git will rebase your changes upon

```
git pull
```

Alternatively, (especially if rebasing is no option for you) you can create a copy of the regular Makefile to use and gitignore:

```
cp Makefile Makefile.local
echo Makefile.local >> .git/info/exclude
make -f Makefile.local
```

However, with that variant you need to keep an eye on the (regular, git-controlled) Makefile and update your local version accordingly if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Why not fix the Makefile to use a variable for the path to the compiler instead of something hard-coded? Then you can just set the proper value in your environment. A lot of these (like CC for the C compiler, CPP for the C Preprocessor, etc, are pre-set by make). If yours is not, you can give it a default value that can be overridden by an environment variable. This example assume GNU make, other make utilities allow similar solutions:

```
FOO ?= /usr/bin/foo

test:
        @echo CC is ${CC}
        @echo FOO is ${FOO}
```

(make sure to use real tabs).

This gives:

```
$ make
CC is cc
FOO is /usr/bin/foo
$ export FOO=/opt/bin/foo
$ make
CC is cc
FOO is /opt/bin/foo
$ make FOO=/just/this/once
CC is cc
FOO is /just/this/once
```

This is a much more maintainable solution, and avoids the risk of one day accidentally pushing your local-only changes upstream.