# how to deal with local/dev only code using git

Tags: git, version-control, ignore

if i have some local debug code or a development web services ip in my sources that i want to keep medium to long term locally, but don't want it in my git repo, what is the best way to accomplish this?

for now i just leave it alone, commit partial files carefully avoiding those lines, and do a series of

```
git stash
git pull --rebase
git stash pop
```

when there are diverging changes etc...

assuming that i cannot or do not want to change the structure of the code to pull these lines out into a file that can be included and/or ignored, how do you deal with this type of situation?

[local Makefile changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262249/managing-local-only-changes-with-git) are discussed here, which seems like the basic idea i want but most of the suggestions are for how to work around it, not really resolve it in a very satisfactory way.

i guess what i am looking for is something like .gitignore for a changeset.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to simply keep a separate branch in your dev server's copy of the repo that you never push publicly, which has your local changes. You can merge in upstream stuff to that branch; as long as you don't merge that branch into an upstream branch those changes will never show up anywhere else.

Another option is that you could break those settings out into a config file that you don't check into Git at all.

Comment: thanks for the answer, not quite what i was looking for.  i clarified my question, these are changes made locally where i am doing the development, for example using dev.missilelauncher.com which doesn't launch missiles, but deploy needs to use api.missilelauncher.com.

Comment: I'd really, really strongly suggest pulling that value out to a config file, but if you don't want to do that, the only other real options you have are either (a) a separate branch, or (b) a smudge/clean filter (which would probably be overkill).

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should put the changes in a branch, and rebase the changes on top of the main development tree.

If, for some reason, you really don't want to create objects in that git database even in a separate branch, then consider cloning your repo into another directory where you only have the private changes checked in.  Then you can pull and rebase over there without worrying about objects creeping into your original repo (which I assume you're scared might accidentally get pushed).

Comment: making another branch seems like it makes things more difficult instead of easier, thanks for the suggestion though.